# Spring & RabbitMQ - register queue at runtime

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

How can I create new queue bound to Fanout exchange and run it during runtime? So far I have this:

```
Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    arguments.put("x-message-ttl", 600000L);

    GenericBeanDefinition runtimeQueueBean = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    runtimeQueueBean.setBeanClass(Queue.class);
    runtimeQueueBean.setLazyInit(false);
    runtimeQueueBean.setAbstract(false);
    runtimeQueueBean.setAutowireCandidate(true);
    ConstructorArgumentValues queueConstrArgs = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
    queueConstrArgs.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, queueName);
    queueConstrArgs.addIndexedArgumentValue(1, true);
    queueConstrArgs.addIndexedArgumentValue(2, false);
    queueConstrArgs.addIndexedArgumentValue(3, false);
    queueConstrArgs.addIndexedArgumentValue(4, arguments);
    runtimeQueueBean.setConstructorArgumentValues(queueConstrArgs);
    this.context.registerBeanDefinition("nejm", runtimeQueueBean);


    GenericBeanDefinition runtimeFanoutExchange = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    runtimeFanoutExchange.setBeanClass(FanoutExchange.class);
    runtimeFanoutExchange.setLazyInit(false);
    runtimeFanoutExchange.setAbstract(false);
    runtimeFanoutExchange.setAutowireCandidate(true);
    ConstructorArgumentValues constructorArgumentValues = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, "staticCache");
    runtimeFanoutExchange.setConstructorArgumentValues(constructorArgumentValues);
    this.context.registerBeanDefinition("staticCache", runtimeFanoutExchange);


    GenericBeanDefinition runtimeBinding = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    runtimeBinding.setBeanClass(Binding.class);
    runtimeBinding.setLazyInit(false);
    runtimeBinding.setAbstract(false);
    runtimeBinding.setAutowireCandidate(true);
    constructorArgumentValues = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, queueName);
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(1, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE);
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(2, "staticCache");
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(3, "");
    runtimeBinding.setConstructorArgumentValues(constructorArgumentValues);
    this.context.registerBeanDefinition("bajnding", runtimeBinding);


    GenericBeanDefinition runtimeMessageListenerAdapter = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    runtimeMessageListenerAdapter.setBeanClass(MessageListenerAdapter.class);
    runtimeMessageListenerAdapter.setLazyInit(false);
    runtimeMessageListenerAdapter.setAbstract(false);
    runtimeMessageListenerAdapter.setAutowireCandidate(true);
    constructorArgumentValues = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, this);
    constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(1, new RuntimeBeanReference("jackson2JsonMessageConverter"));
    runtimeMessageListenerAdapter.setConstructorArgumentValues(constructorArgumentValues);
    this.context.registerBeanDefinition("mla2", runtimeMessageListenerAdapter);



    GenericBeanDefinition runtimeContainerExchange = new GenericBeanDefinition();
    runtimeContainerExchange.setBeanClass(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class);
    runtimeContainerExchange.setLazyInit(false);
    runtimeContainerExchange.setAbstract(false);
    runtimeContainerExchange.setAutowireCandidate(true);
    MutablePropertyValues propertyValues = new MutablePropertyValues();
    propertyValues.addPropertyValue("connectionFactory", new RuntimeBeanReference("connectionFactory"));
    propertyValues.addPropertyValue("queues", new RuntimeBeanReference("nejm"));
    propertyValues.addPropertyValue("messageListener", new RuntimeBeanReference("mla2"));
    runtimeContainerExchange.setPropertyValues(propertyValues);
    this.context.registerBeanDefinition("defqueue", runtimeContainerExchange);
```

The problem is that queue/exchange is not created at the runtime, and I have to manually start the listener (unless I call this.context.start() - but I don't know if this is correct approach).

My question - is there some way to magically start all generated beans in runtime (something like this.context.refresh() - this exists but doesn't work or similar)?

**UPDATE:**

This is how I do it currently (this approach works, but don't know if correct one)

```
    Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    arguments.put("x-message-ttl", 600000L);
    Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true, false, false, arguments);

    FanoutExchange exchange = new FanoutExchange("staticCache");

    Binding binding = new Binding(queueName, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, "staticCache", "", null);

    rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(queue);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(this, this.converter));

    container.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that way. `BeanDefinition` and `this.context.registerBeanDefinition` are for parsing phase of your application context lifecycle.

If you app is already there, the application context won't accepts any `BeanDefinition`.

Yes, you can declare `Queue` and its `Binding` to the exchange manually at runtime. And also you even can create `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` manually and make it worked.

And what is good for you that you just need to use their classes manually to instantiate. There is just need to supply container environment (e.g. inject `this.applicationContext` to the `listenerContainer` object).

For the declaration on the Broker you must use `RabbitAdmin` bean from your `applicationContext`.

From other side there is no reason to start a new `listenerContainer` manually. The existing one can supplied with your new `Queue` at runtime.

Comment: can you please check the update to the question - this updated approach works, but don't know if it is correct one

Comment: ??? You do that through the `GenericBeanDefinition` and I recommend to go a head with regular Java code, e.g. `new Queue()` and so on.

Comment: yes, this is what I did in update part of my question above. I don't know if you can see it?

Comment: Yes, your last solution is correct. But try to avoid `registerSingleton` manually. It won't work for all cases. You just need to declare your queue using `rabbitAdmin` like you have done for the binding. No need to reinitialize it and no need to register container as a bean. Everything else is good.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I don't event need container.afterPropertiesSet(); (works without it) so I deleted it from the code. The updated code should now be OK.